# How do I put text in the middle of these tables?

Tags: html, html-table

I'm new to html/css, and I'm coding a website with a rather intricate layout.

[image]

Because I'm a musician, I want to have a personal website, but I have a problem.  I have these two tables, one on the left and one on the right, and I want text in the middle of the tables, but it doesn't go there and instead, goes on top of the tables.  Is there any way I can make it so that it can do this?

Here's my code:

```
<html>
    <table width="400" height="675" border="5" style="float: left" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
              (embedded gadget)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

<h2 align="center">FAQ</h2>

<table width="400" height="675" border="5" style="float: right;" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
        (information on the album here)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</html>
```

Comment: It is working good for me http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/8bLyS/

Answer (score 1):

First of all I recommend using [bootstrap-3](http://www.getbootstrap.com) as it is very well documented and easy to make good looking sites.

That being said I am not great at HTML or CSS either.  Also you are not closing your table with .  You could try doing this:

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="400" height="675" border="5"cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              (embedded gadget)
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table width="400" height="675" border="5"cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              (information on the album here)
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Not working, instead it's doing the exact same thing, except it doesn't have word wrap.

Comment: Are you willing for me to show you how to do it using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

You have a HTML error where you haven't closed your table tags.

As a beginner in HTML you need some tools to check what you've created is valid. Try running your page through a [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org) which will tell you about errors like that And/or use View Source in Firefox which highlights errors like that in red.

Comment: Thanks for the resource, I'll definitely use this, stating I found 12 errors in the entirety of my code, which is horrible.